# Building Python3 auth proxy server between PostgreSQL and Dynamics 365 Web API

Tags: python, django, postgresql, proxy, microsoft-dynamics

After several days of some progress, I am coming to terms with the fact I lack the knowledge, or level of skill, to put all of these pieces together and finish this project. Thus, I am appealing to, and grateful to, anyone who can help me out with this.

**Technology**

- CentOS 7.5
- Python 3.6.0
- Django 1.10.5
- PostreSQL 9.2
- Microsoft CRM Dynamics 365 online which has most current client data, thus have to use the Web API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx

**Issue**

- CRM has the most current client data in it and want to bring it into PostgreSQL to use for numerous things
- Want to use `www_fdw` since it is the only foreign data wrapper I have seen for PostgreSQL than can use Web API's: https://github.com/cyga/www_fdw/wiki
- The Dynamics Web API uses OAuth2 and `www_fdw` does not support any type of authentication natively
- Talked to the dev of `www_fdw` who recommended making a proxy server to handle the OAuth2 authentication with Microsoft
- PostgreSQL with `www_fdw` would talk to the proxy, which would in turn send authentication to Microsoft culminating in the ability to treat the Web API as a Foreign Table so that it is treated like any other table

**The three parts and what has been tried so far**

*Three parts = `www_fdw` + proxy server + OAuth2*

1. `www_fdw`: I have setup using the following parameters based on this: https://github.com/cyga/www_fdw/wiki/Examples

   ```
   DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS www_fdw CASCADE;
   CREATE EXTENSION www_fdw;
   CREATE SERVER crm FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER www_fdw OPTIONS
       (uri 'http://localhost:12345');  -- proxy server
   CREATE USER MAPPING FOR current_user SERVER crm;

   -- for testing trying to get 'name' out of the CRM 'accounts' table and
      naming the foreign table the same as the table in CRM
   CREATE FOREIGN TABLE accounts (
       name varchar(255)
   ) SERVER crm;
   ```
2. `crmproxytest.py` for the *proxy server*, I have been trying to make a bare bones one using this link: http://effbot.org/librarybook/simplehttpserver.htm

   ```
   import socketserver
   import http.server
   import urllib

   PORT = 12345

   class Proxy(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
       def do_GET(self):
           self.copyfile(urllib.urlopen(self.path), self.wfile)

   httpd = socketserver.ForkingTCPServer(('', PORT), Proxy)
   print ("serving at port", PORT)
   httpd.serve_forever()
   ```

   This seems to work as it says `serving at port 12345` on console, shows up running `nmap -sT -O localhost`, there is some activity on the console running the server when `nmap` is run. Otherwise can't get any activity out of it.

   Running `SELECT * FROM accounts` from PostgreSQL results in `Can't get a response from server: Failed to connect to ::1: Permission denied`.
3. *OAuth2*. I put together `crm.py` and got it working after talking to Microsoft,  sorting through their documentation, and the finding this link: http://alexanderdevelopment.net/post/2016/11/27/dynamics-365-and-python-integration-using-the-web-api/

   In a nutshell, you have to register your app with Azure Active Directory so that you can get a `client_id`, `client_secret`, in addition to being able to obtain the `OAuth 2.0 Token URI` and the `OAuth 2.0 Authorization URI`. You can then send a request to the `authorizationendpoint`, which if the credentials match it returns an token, the token is then sent to the `tokenendpoint` and access to the Web API is ultimately granted.

   This is the code I ended up with that works, retrieves data from the Dynamics Web API, and populates it in the console:

   ```
   import requests  
   import json

   #set these values to retrieve the oauth token
   crmorg = 'https://ORG.crm.dynamics.com' #base url for crm org  
   clientid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' #application client id  
   client_secret = 'SUPERSECRET'
   username = 'asd@asd.com' #username  
   userpassword = 'qwerty' #password
   authorizationendpoint =  'https://login.windows.net/ZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZZZZZZZZZ/oauth2/authorize'
   tokenendpoint = 'https://login.windows.net/ZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZZZZZZZZZ/oauth2/token' #oauth token endpoint

   #set these values to query your crm data
   crmwebapi = 'https://ORG.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2' #full path to web api endpoint  
   crmwebapiquery = '/accounts?$select=name&$orderby=name' #web api query (include leading /)

   #build the authorization token request
   tokenpost = {  
       'client_id':clientid,
       'client_secret': client_secret,
       'resource':crmorg,
       'oauthUrl': authorizationendpoint,
       'username':username,
       'password':userpassword,
       'grant_type':'password'
       }

   #make the token request
   tokenres = requests.post(tokenendpoint, data=tokenpost)

   #check the value of tokenres
   print(tokenres)

   #set accesstoken variable to empty string
   accesstoken = ''

   #extract the access token
   try:  
       accesstoken = tokenres.json()['access_token']
   except(KeyError):  
       #handle any missing key errors
       print('Could not get access token')

   # check point for debugging
   # print(accesstoken)

   #if we have an accesstoken
   if(accesstoken!=''):  
       #prepare the crm request headers
       crmrequestheaders = {
           'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accesstoken,
           'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0',
           'OData-Version': '4.0',
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           'Prefer': 'odata.maxpagesize=500',
           'Prefer': 'odata.include-annotations=OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue'
           }

       #make the crm request
       crmres = requests.get(crmwebapi+crmwebapiquery, headers=crmrequestheaders)

       try:
           #get the response json
           crmresults = crmres.json()

           #loop through it
           for x in crmresults['value']:
               # print (x['fullname'] + ' - ' + x['contactid'])
               print (x['name'])
       except KeyError:
           #handle any missing key errors
           print('Could not parse CRM results')
   ```

   This works like a charm, but is really for testing the OAuth2. The query in combination of variables `crmwebapi` and `crmwebapiquery` doesn't really need to be in there since PostgreSQL, if the FDW is working right, should allow for running SQL queries against the Web API.

Anyway, I hope I explained this all well enough. It seems that I got three independent pieces of the puzzle that work, or kind of work, but bringing it all together is where I am stuck. `crm.py` and `crmtest.py` probably need to be combined, but not sure how.

Thanks in advance for the help!

EDIT: Apparently had `www_ftw` everywhere instead of `www_fdw`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up the FDW in Step 1 looks okay to me.

Your Python script in Step 2 needs a shebang at the top. Otherwise it is treated as bash, so the first 3 lines run [`import(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/import) and save screenshots to new files named `http.server`, `socketserver`, and `urllib`. That keeps the script busy for a little while before it dies on the `PORT` line. In the meantime (or even after it dies), running just `curl http://localhost:12345` gives the same error as Postgres:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 12345: Connection refused
```

After adding `#!/usr/bin/env python3` your script will answer requests. For instance I can say `curl http://localhost:12345/etc/passwd` and get a result.

I'm not sure how you intend to wire up Step 3 (the OAuth), but hopefully this answer will get you past what is blocking you right now.

Comment: Hi Paul, I will work with what you suggested this morning. I think my biggest issue at this point is joining together Step 2 and 3: setting up a persistent process that Postgres can talk to that mediates the authorization to Microsoft's OAuth2 so it can use a foreign data wrapper to query the Dynamics CRM Web API.

Comment: @sockpuppet did Paul's answer help? If so, please make sure you accept it or add a comment explaining why this was not a solution.